# Replace filename to a string of the first line in multiple files in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, bioinformatics, fasta

I have multiple fasta files, where the first line always contains a `>` with multiple words, for example:

```
File_1.fasta: 
>KY620313.1 Hepatitis C virus isolate sP171215 polyprotein gene, complete cds
File_2.fasta: 
>KY620314.1 Hepatitis C virus isolate sP131957 polyprotein gene, complete cds
File_3.fasta: 
>KY620315.1 Hepatitis C virus isolate sP127952 polyprotein gene, complete cds
```

I would like to take the word starting with `sP*` from each file and rename each file to this string (for example: File_1.fasta to sP171215.fasta).
So far I have this:

```
    $ for match in "$(grep -ro '>')";do
          fname=$("echo $match|awk '{print $6}'")
          echo mv "$match" "$fname"
      done
```

But it doesn't work, I always get the error:

> grep: warning: recursive search of stdin

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
grep '>' *.fasta | while read -r line ; do
  new_name="$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 6)"
  old_name="$(echo $line | cut -d':' -f 1)"
  mv $old_name "$new_name.fasta"
done
```

1. It searches for *.fasta files and handles every "hitted" line
2. it splits each result of grep by spaces and gets the 6th element as new name
3. it splits each result of grep by : and gets the first element as old name
4. it
   moves/renames from old filename to new filename

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on with this code.
For a start, .. I actually don't get this particular error, and this might be due to different versions.
It might resolve to the fact that grep interprets `'>'` the same as `>` due to bash expansion being done badly. I would suggest maybe going for `"\>"`.

Secondly:

`fname=$("echo $match|awk '{print $6}'")`
The quotes inside serve unintended purpose. Your code should like like this, if anything:
`fname="$(echo $match|awk '{print $6}')"`

Lastly, to properly retrieve your data, this should be your final code:

```sh
for match in "$(grep -Hr "\>")"; do
  fname="$(echo "$match" | cut -d: -f1)"
  new_fname="$(echo "$match" | grep -o "sP[^ ]*")".fasta
  echo mv "$fname" "$new_fname"
done
```

Explanations:
`grep -H` -> you want your grep to explicitly use "Include Filename", just in case other shell environments decide to alias `grep` to `grep -h (no filenames)`

you don't want to be doing `grep -o` on your file search, as you want to have both the filename and the "new filename" in one data entry.

Although, i don't see why you would search for '>' and not directory for 'sP' as such:

```sh
for match in "$(grep -Hro "sP[0-9]*")"
```

This is not the exact same behaviour, and has different edge cases, but it just might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Quite straightforward in (g)awk :

create a file "script.awk":

```
FNR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (index($i, "sP")==1) {
            print "mv", FILENAME, $i ".fasta"
            nextfile
        }
    }
}
```

use it :

`awk -f script.awk *.fasta > cmmd.txt`

check the content of the output.

```
mv File_1.fasta sP171215.fasta
mv File_2.fasta sP131957.fasta
```

if ok, launch rename with `. cmmd.txt`

Answer (score 0):

For all fasta files in directory, search their first line for the first word starting with `sP` and rename them using that word as the basename.

Using a bash array:

```
for f in *.fasta; do
    arr=( $(head -1 "$f") )
    for word in "${arr[@]}"; do
        [[ "$word" =~ ^sP* ]] && echo mv "$f" "${word}.fasta" && break
    done
done
```

or using grep:

```
for f in *.fasta; do
    word=$(head -1 "$f" | grep -o "\bsP\w*")
    [ -z "$word" ] || echo mv "$f" "${word}.fasta"
done
```

Note: remove `echo` after you are ok with testing.